# Setup Twitter intent url to open IOS camera to take picture

Tags: ios, api, twitter

Wanted to attach a parameter to the Twitter intent URL created:
https://tech.cymi.org/tweet-intents

And prompt IOS user to activate media upload (e.g. open their camera app) to take a picture

I'm guessing the default Twitter intent URL doesn't allow it and a script should be created but not sure which direction to take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security purposes I don't think they exposed that - as per the intent docs https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/guides/web-intent you are limited to just those parameters. iOS alone btw has one of the strictest security measures such as no video autoplay, user-activated actions to prevent automation; basically any interference with user comfort and engagement is deeply guarded that even with such intent query it would likely not work as needed. You could possibly create a file input field and when pressed you can have it access the camera and append that to a webhook where you can proceed with your project but as for the intent mechanism in itself I think you are limited.